# How to drag an image using pageX and PageY of Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello folks I'm novice to Javascript and Jquery. First of all i have an image with id given to it i.e #imag_4 and i have kept this on click function inside the function imageDrag().When i do click on the image, i pass the image to the dragMe() function and there i apply pageX and pageY . I am getting the value of pagex and pagey but the image is not moving as the mouse moves... Below is the code

```
function imageDrag(){
   var imageDragged = null;

   $('.flexslider .slides #listid_4 #imag_4').on('click', function (e) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      if (imageDragged === null) {
         imageDragged = $(this);
            console.log(imageDragged);
         drag(imageDragged);
      }
   });
}
```

I know there we have Jquery UI 's draggable function, i do not want to use that method.
Below is my dragMe function..

```
function dragMe(imageDragged) {
   $(this).on('mousemove', function (e) {  
      imageDragged.css({
         left: e.pageX,
         top: e.pageY
      });
   });
}
```

Comment: @caramba do u know the answer

Comment: Maybe add `'px'` to the values of `e.pageX` and `e.pageY`? E.g.: `e.pageX + 'px'`. Also: shouldn't `drag(imageDragged);` be `dragMe(imageDragged);`?

Comment: @user1846192 yeah i m done with dat change '

Comment: Like here its woking http://jsfiddle.net/5zVB8/17/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you're invoking `drag` function, whereas you defined `dragMe` function.

Secondly, jquery `click` is invoked when you literally click with mouse button i.e. mouse press and then mouse release. You should use 'mousedown' event to catch this drag-start event.

The last thing is: you should handle `mouserelease` event to stop dragging the element.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xkYNU/) is modified & simplified to span element example

Comment: Like here it is working  http://jsfiddle.net/5zVB8/17/ but  not working at my side